# Python script can't find ENV variable run with CRON in docker container

Tags: python, docker, cron, environment

I want to run a Python script in a Docker container with crontab, now cron successfully run the python script but it can't find ENV variable given from Dockerfile, when i run echo $DOG from inside the container is shows up expected string "dog" or when ik manaully run the python script `/> python dog.py` it can find the ENV variables. So the ENV are in the OS inside the container.

Why isnt it reachable for the script running by cron?

Crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /app/dog.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
# empty line
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

WORKDIR /app/

COPY crontab .

COPY dog.py .

RUN chmod -R 755 /app/

RUN crontab /app/crontab

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

dog.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
# Check os env variables
if "DOG" in os.environ:
    dog = os.environ.get("DOG")
    print(dog)
else:
    print("no env")
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
---
version: "3.8"
services:
  prd-workorder-worker:
    build: .
    environment:
    - DOG=dog
```

Comment: Seems that the processes started by the cron are running with another ENV ... I'd wrap the `cron -f` in  a bash/sh script that first logs the env var ,or all the ENV while you are it, just to be sure that the env var arrives correctly and afterwards start the `cron -f`. Then I'd try either from the python or another script in the cron jobs listing everything in the ENV and check the differences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i have solved it by running a bash script that put all variables to /etc/environment when the container is started.

Dockerfile

```
...

CMD ["./entry.sh"]
```

entry.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment

cron -f
```

Comment: You can do it without dedicated script like this:
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "printenv > /etc/environment && cron -f"]